# Excel 2010 Custom right-click menu within cell

Tags: excel, contextmenu

I spent many hours to find the solution without success.
I try to add custom action in right-click menu but WHEN I'm typing in the cell so in edit mode.
All topics explain how to add action in right-click menu but only when you select a cell not when you are within.

This is my personal right-click menu
[image: This is my personnal right-clik menu]

This the contextual menu when you right-click in edition mode:
[image: This the contextual menu when you right-clik in edition mode]

My code for the standard right-click menu:

```
Public Function addMenu(menuName As String, menuActionMacro As String, pictureFaceId As Integer, beginGroup As Boolean)

    If checkMenuNotExist(menuActionMacro) Then
        Dim cbButt As CommandBarButton
        Dim cb As CommandBar

        Set cb = Application.CommandBars("cell")
        Set cbButt = cb.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)

        cbButt.beginGroup = beginGroup
        cbButt.Caption = menuName
        cbButt.OnAction = menuActionMacro
        cbButt.FaceId = pictureFaceId
        cbButt.Tag = menuActionMacro

    End If
End Function
```

Is somebody how to add action in the editing right-clik menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used my [MenuRighter](http://yoursumbuddy.com/menurighter/) add-in, and its "Show Labels on Menus" feature to determine that the context menu you're interested in is #58 and is called "Formula Bar". I didn't think that one would be changable, but I was able to add the File menu to it.

So try this:

```
Public Function addMenu(menuName As String, menuActionMacro As String, pictureFaceId As Integer, beginGroup As Boolean)

    If checkMenuNotExist(menuActionMacro) Then
        Dim cbButt As CommandBarButton
        Dim cb As CommandBar

        Set cb = Application.CommandBars("Formula Bar")
        Set cbButt = cb.Controls.Add(msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)

        cbButt.beginGroup = beginGroup
        cbButt.Caption = menuName
        cbButt.OnAction = menuActionMacro
        cbButt.FaceId = pictureFaceId
        cbButt.Tag = menuActionMacro

    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to share this document with all employees (+500) and with GPO, I can't install specific complement on each computer

Comment: I thought your question was how to add to the Cell Edit menu using VBA. That's what my answer shows.  Did you try running the VBA? If that's not the question, please clarify it. You don't need to install the add-in I referred to - it's just what I used to find out that that shortcut menu you want to modify is called "Formula Bar."